# custom key binding in xmonad without affecting other bindings

Tags: xmonad

I am using xmonad, and wanted a nice way to lock the screen. So I installed slock (apt-get install slock), and it works great.

Then I wanted an easy key sequence to trigger slock, so I defined this new function in xmonad.hs:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask}) = M.fromList $
        [ ((modMask .|. controlMask, xK_l),
           spawn "slock")
        ]
```

and added `keys = myKeys` in the main function.

This enabled me to nicely lock the screen using `Ctrl+Alt+l`, but then none of the other xmonad shortcuts would work!

Is there a way for me to add a single new key binding, but without altering any of the existing bindings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've probably guessed, by setting `keys = myKeys` in the main function, what you've done is to override the default settings. You can add your keys using the `additionalKeys` operator, like so:

```
main =
   xmonad $ desktopConfig `additionalKeys` myKeys
```

Or, if you have some other customisations to desktopConfig,

```
main =
   xmonad $ desktopConfig
    { 
       -- other customisations
    } `additionalKeys` myKeys
```

Comment: I've got some errors: `xmonad.hs:18:52: Not in scope: 'M.fromList'`
`xmonad.hs:28:12: Not in scope: 'additionalKeys'` where should I get those from?

Comment: Add `import qualified Data.Map as M` and `import XMonad.Util.EZConfig ( additionalKeys )` to the top of your file.